# PHP mail function is sending emails in Gmail's SPAM folder, How to get rid of it?

Tags: php, smtp

i am using this code :

```
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

it sends email to my gmail's SPAM folder . 

Suggest any solution .

i dont want to use  any PEAR MAIL type way to send email or dont want to require and include any file.

This functions works without including/requiring any additional php file.

Comment: It can't send mail to your gmail's spam folder, as your email address is presumably not "someone@example.com". Please provide your real code.

Comment: real code is not different except the email addresse. Because in real code to and from is populating dynamically. Now it starts working in gmail but not in hotmail

Comment: The email address is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

You should use proper header like this from PHP manual

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: after setting headers i can now get email in my gmail Inox but not in my hotmail INOX :(  , but then also thanks for ur headers suggestion

Answer (score 3):

The Gmail spam filter has lots of parts to it which determine the spamminess of mail. You could start by seeing the [SPF](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33786) record for your domain. Avoid using sales language, HTML and colours where possible in your email.

There's also an old but fun [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FVme_xIRYk) from Google about how their spam filtering works.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the headers. I don't know how GMail works internally, but I've found on my projects that setting Reply-To can Content-Type headers seems to fix this.

See [PHP mail() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for an example of doing this.

(Note: I've got a PHP questionnaire/response system that sets these headers and the e-mails come through correctly to GMail, Hotmail and Yahoo! Mail).